# Load generator for testing power supplies

Tags: power-supply, fan, dummy-load

I have some DC-DC power supplies that I would like to test. (about 10 or so).

PSU specs:

- Input 6-30V DC
- Output 8V DC, 2.5 Amps max.

As I don't have the budget for a DC Load generator, I'm looking for a cost effective alternative to test with.

I have salvaged a PC fan from a Dell Workstation. DA15050B12H - AVC 150mm Ball bearing fan, DC12V 1.8 Amps.

Will this fan behave as an analog of an 8 volt 2.4 amp load as I would expect?  I'm about to do some testing and measuring, I don't really care too much about the fan, but I wouldn't want to damage the PSUs.

Are there better load generation tricks I could consider without spending a fortune?

Comment: A fan functions more as a constant-resistance device than a constant-power device. It will draw *less* than 1.8 A @ 8 V, not more.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Arachnid Labs Re:load 2](https://www.tindie.com/products/arachnidlabs/reload-the-simple-robust-affordable-dummy-load/) starts at $15, but you may need to get the larger heat sink, which will cost $5 more.

Answer (score 6):

I would just get a bunch of 10Ω, 10W resistors. Each one will draw 0.8A from an 8V supply, and you can connect 1, 2 or 3 of them in parallel to see how the power supplies behave at different loads.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

- buy low-voltage (eg 12V, 24V) bulbs, connect them in parallel or in series (pros: low-cost, especially in case of larger loads, cons: probably have to build some box to hold the sockets for the bulbs),
- buy multiple power resistors, connect them in parallel or in series (pros: moderately flexible load configurations are possible, cons: moderate cost),
- build a controllable DC load circuit, with one or more FETs attached to a heatsink (pros: very flexible, cons: might need a larger heatsink, and probably a fan as well, depending on the magnitude of the power to be dissipated; higher complexity),
- buy a controllable DC load circuit ready-made (pros: buying is simple, cons: higher costs).